# Use index match to return multiple values and display them in a drop down box

Tags: indexing, match, dropdown

please help! I'm struggling with this one.

I have two worksheets. In worksheet 1 is a list of case reference numbers for people (each person is identified by a PIN).

The case numbers are in column A and the PIN in column B. Some PINS will be listed more than once and have more than one case number.

On worksheet 2 is a list of the PINs in column A with the persons name etc alongside. In column H I would like to enter an index match formula to match the pin number in say A2 against the PIN's in worksheet 1 and return the case number in column H on worksheet 2.

I can get this to work with no problem but it only returns the first value.

I wonder if there is any way of creating a drop down box so that in column H on worksheet 2 it will show ALL the case numbers found on worksheet 1 that match the PIN in say A2 on worksheet 2?

Please help, it's driving me crackers and I just cant work it out...

Lolli x